# Angular - NG SERVE doesnt work outta nowhere / node:internal/errors:563 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Tags: node.js, angular, stack-trace, serve, ng

I started learning Angular 8+, and everytime i start a new project, the very next day i cant NG SERVE anymore.

I've tryed lots of tutorial to fix, but nothing works. Sometimes, i change zero lines from one day to another, and the NG SERVE just stops.

Here is the LOG:

```
`**Initial Chunk Files | Names         | Raw Size
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 82.71 kB |
main.js             | main          |  5.75 kB |
styles.css          | styles        | 95 bytes |

                    | Initial Total | 88.55 kB

Application bundle generation complete. [1.845 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
node:internal/errors:563
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
    at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:207:21)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024     Edition)\Tutorials\Section 01 - Getting Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:647:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._boundHandleError (Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024     Edition)\Tutorials\Section 01 - Getting Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-    handler.js:303:43)
    at Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024 Edition)\Tutorials\Section 01 - Getting     Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:137:5
    at foreach (Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024 Edition)\Tutorials\Section 01 -     Getting Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:41:5)
    at fsWatchBroadcast (Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024 Edition)\Tutorials\Section     01 - Getting Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:136:3)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (Z:\Courses\Angular - The Complete Guide (2024     Edition)\Tutorials\Section 01 - Getting Started\project\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-            handler.js:185:9)
    at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:213:12) {
  errno: -4094,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  filename: null
}

Node.js v20.10.0**`
```

I've tryed updating, upgrading, but it only makes it worse sometimes, and i can only fix by creating another project from scratch.

I tryed leaning, and expected it to be a piece of cake given my Front-End background, but this NG SERVE problem is troublesome. As i said before, Updating/Upgrading doesnt work.